# Are there disadvantages on using as partition column a non-primitive column (date) in Hive?

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, partition

Is there any reason why I shouldn't use a column formatted as `date` as the partitioning column in a table in Apache Hive?

The official documentation says:

> Although currently there is not restriction on the data type of the partitioning column, allowing non-primitive columns to be partitioning column probably doesn't make sense. The dynamic partitioning column's type should be derived from the expression. The data type has to be able to be converted to a string in order to be saved as a directory name in HDFS.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/DynamicPartitions#DynamicPartitions-Designissues

I don't see why columns formatted as `date` would create any issue, since by design these could be converted into `string`.

Comment: Partitions are created as folder in HDFS and HDFS can it will be tough for while parsing from meta ... ie if folder name is  (2016/01/01) how hive will know it is folder name or directory structure ...

Comment: The default format of a `date` is `YYYY-­MM-­DD` ([link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-Dates)), so I don't think that would create any issue.

Comment: I would say the documentation is not upto date. When it was written the only DATE type available was TIMESTAMP and that would have been cumbersome. TIMESTAMP (Note: Only available starting with Hive 0.8.0)
DATE (Note: Only available starting with Hive 0.12.0)